# Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition - Missing Project Templates

Tags: templates

all
I'm moving to Vs 2022 community and, after install completed, creating new projects I don't see templates.
Many thanks for any answer.

I tried more solutions as download .Net 8 then restart pc, repairing installation then restart pc and so on but issue is not resolved. Also, I not found some link for download templates manually except a project on sourceforge but I prefer using "official" templates.